# How to show checkboxes in nicely aligned rows when using ng-repeat?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

In my HTML page I retrieve boolean data from database, I want to show them in a grid, but they alway looks ugly

I use

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="tab in allTabs"><md-checkbox>{{tab.name}}</md-checkbox></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This makes one row, I want it more smart to fit in a specific width and create another row  if the number of items exceeds

Comment: You would have to create a new `<tr>` when you wanted them to be on a new line. Try putting in another `ng-repeat` that controlled how many rows there are. Then the inside `ng-repeat` would produce the tabs for that row.

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle to show the problem? Answers you get will be easier for you to implement this way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using angular material design..
You can see below designs here I have four checkboxes in a line and if there are more than four, It'll go to next line

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="25" flex="45" content-layout-align="center start" ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="tab.value" aria-label="tab.key">
      {{tab.key}}
    </md-checkbox>
  </md-input-container>
</div>

   $scope.allTabs = [{
     key: 'Courier Docket',
     value: false
   }, {
     key: 'Completion Report',
     value: false
   }, {
     key: 'Images',
     value: false
   }, {
     key: 'Fourth One',
     value: false
   }];
```

**EDIT**

I am adding the jsfiddle link for this answer..

**[JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/imraqes/f5tjox5y/)**

Comment: Can I increase number of items in the row?

Comment: Yes, just change the `flex` value - `flex="20"` would create 5 per row, `flex="10"` would create 10 per row and so on

Comment: I tried but doesn't change it, still the same 4 items /row!

Comment: do you have more than 4 in your array ?

Comment: Yes, about 13 items, there are long spaces between them

Comment: If you are following exactly the answered way than it should work. Check your console if you are getting any errors ? or any other typos

Comment: I copied it as it is!

Comment: This would be much more understandable for all involved if @Rakeschand placed their answer in a working jsfiddle. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Rakeschand Nice. I was able to change the flex to adjust the number per row. This is definitely a correct answer at this point.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-repeat in your md-checkbox this will allow you to add more css to td and you can specify the width of your td in that in that case it will automatically move to next row

```
  <table>
    <tr >
      <td style="width:100px"><md-checkbox ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">{{tab.name}}</md-checkbox></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```